# xampp mysql-Instance won't start anymore

Tags: windows, mariadb, xampp

Since 20.10.2023 the mysql-instance from my xampp-Installation (8.2.4) doesn't start anymore. It tries to for a few seconds, but crashes with a not meaningful text (you will find it below, german). I didn't made any changes on my system almost 2 weeks before that to this date and now. Nothing with the OS, no new Software, no pragramming, ... nothing what could cause this problem. In this timeframe i almost only played some games and used my Browser.

Of course i wanted to see the error-log, and doing that i wanted to use the easy way with the button in the xampp-Control-Panel, which didn't work. A message prompted saying that it couldn't find the log-file. On top of that there were more messages with weird cutted paths. This problem (opening the mysql-error-log via the xampp-button) was solved on my own, by removing spaces in my installation-path, which xampp suggested. It's crazy that my installation is working for yaears this way (with spaces) and suddenly it causes problems. Nevermind.

Now accessing the mysql-error-log (you will find it below) i saw several entries pointing out that ibd-files were missing. I recovered theese from old backups, but definetely didn't changed anything on theese files or related databases. Again, it's weird that this is suddenly a problem, when it worked before (without recovering theese files). Maybe Windows-Defender had an impact? I checked - no, it didn't. And i am not using any other antivir-Software.

Without theese ibd-missing-errors the current mysql-error-log and an old one from before the problem almost look identical. Comparing theese will result in the fact, that it crashes after the line "Server socket created on IP: '::'.". In the old working log after this line mysqld.exe would be started successfully. Currently this isn't the case anymore and i don't know why.

Do you guys have any ideas? Can you please help me?

What i tried:

Since the text in the xampp-Control-Panel suggested me to use Admin-Rights and remove spaces in the installation-path (when i wanted to open the error-log), i did exactly that.

- xampp-Installation duplicated in a path without spaces
- xampp-Installation with Adminstrator-Rights started

This wasn't nessecary before, and the only two things it solved was a) accessing the error-logs via the Control-Panel and b) no hints in the Control-Panel to this topic any longer.

I recovered from a backup 13.06.2023

- slave_master_info.ibd & .frm
- slave_relay_log_info.ibd & .frm
- slave_worker_info.ibd & .frm

With that the related errors in the mysql-error-log dissapeared.

There are multiple "zen_civ5"-tables where the ibd-file is missing also. Theese are very old tables, which i deleted (DROP) over 1-2 years ago. Again, it is weird that the system is insisting at theese tables. Well, for the sake of solving the problem i imported theese tables from a very old backup (2019), which helped removing the related errors in the log.

At this point the log didn't help me any further, because the last line is "Server socket created on IP: '::'.".
So i took a shot into the blue and looked for port 3306. Maybe another program decidede to use it? I used 'netstat -aon | find "3306"' in the console without any results. So the port is free to use. (3306 is the right one, because its visible in the Control-Panel and is in the my.ini from mysql.)

I also tried changing the port to 3307 and deleting ibdata1, ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1,ib_logfile101 in xampp/mysql/data, like suggested in many other questions on the internet (changing it in my.ini from mysql and php.ini from php). Didn't help either.

I also downloaded two fresh xampp-Installations (normal and portable) and set it up quickly (correcting paths). Both run apache flawlessly, but both have the same problem with mysql. So its almost certain that is has nothing to do with my installation. It has to be something with my system. Or what do you think?

=== Ressource #1 Text from the xampp-Control-Panel ===

```
19:11:31  [main]    Dein Benutzerprofil besitzt keine Administratorenrechte! Das reicht aus für die meisten
19:11:31  [main]    Anwendungsfunktionen, aber wann immer du etwas mit Windows-Diensten tun möchtest,
19:11:31  [main]    wird eine Sicherheitsabfrage erscheinen oder etwas wird garnicht erst funktionieren!
19:11:31  [main]    Also denke daran diese Anwendung mit Administratorrechten zu starten!

19:11:31  [main]    ACHTUNG: Der XAMPP Installationspfad enthält Leerzeichen. Dies könnte die Funktionalität von Programmen/Scripten beeinflussen

17:21:10  [mysql]   Autostart aktiv: Starte...
17:21:10  [mysql]   Versuche MySQL zu starten...
17:21:11  [mysql]   Statusänderung erkannt: gestartet
17:21:15  [mysql]   Statusänderung erkannt: gestoppt
17:21:15  [mysql]   Fehler: MySQL wurde unerwartet beendet
17:21:15  [mysql]   Ursache könnte ein geblockter Port, fehlende Abhängigkeiten,
17:21:15  [mysql]   fehlende Berechtigungen, ein Absturz oder ein Abbruch einer anderen Methode sein.
17:21:15  [mysql]   Drücke den Logs Button um error logs zu sehen und prüfe
17:21:15  [mysql]   im Windows Event Viewer für weitere Hinweise
17:21:15  [mysql]   Wenn du weitere Hilfe benötigst, kopiere den kompletten Inhalt des Log Fensters
17:21:15  [mysql]   und füge ihn als Ergänzung in einem neuen Forum Eintrag hinzu.
```

=== Ressource #2 mysql_error-Log when the problem occured ===

```
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 16744
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\slave_master_info.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`slave_master_info``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`slave_master_info` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`slave_relay_log_info``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`slave_relay_log_info` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\mysql\slave_worker_info.ibd' OS error: 71
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``mysql`.`slave_worker_info``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `mysql`.`slave_worker_info` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\log_admin.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`log_admin``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`log_admin` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\log_dev.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`log_dev``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`log_dev` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\log_user.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`log_user``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`log_user` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\mls_areas.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`mls_areas``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`mls_areas` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\mls_content.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`mls_content``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`mls_content` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\mls_types.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`mls_types``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`mls_types` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\zen_civ5\project_settings.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``zen_civ5`.`project_settings``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `zen_civ5`.`project_settings` because it could not be opened.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 266632383; transaction id 65753929
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231026 21:45:53
2023-10-26 21:45:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

=== Ressource #3 current mysql_error-Log after my measures ===

```
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 16164
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 266632410; transaction id 65753929
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Software\_Proggen\xampp-8.2.4\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231027 18:42:58
2023-10-27 18:42:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

=== Ressource #4 normal mysql_error-Log before the problem occured ===

this worked flawlessly since 20.10.2023

```
2023-03-18 19:48:19 19a4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.2 started; log sequence number 200477146
2023-03-18 19:48:19 7788 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-03-18 19:48:19 6564 [Note] C:\software\xampp7.0.24\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.28-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-04-13  4:21:27 7904 [Note] C:\software\xampp7.0.24\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

The MariaDB physical backup you have isn't something you can take an InnoDB table (ibd+frm) file from and restore it to the original. There are deep ties to others of the backup.

The backup can only be restored completely or not at all.

[DO NOT EVER DELETE ib_logfile*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/330567/restoring-old-raw-backup-in-mariadb-10-8-1-without-ib-logfile0/330568#330568), you will loose your data.

On the deleted files that are still there, manually `drop table zen_civ5.log_user` and same with the other tables.

Because `mysql.slave*` are system tables, run `mariadb-upgrade.exe` to recreate these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isnt really my problem here.
I didn't delete ib logfile. I don't have a possibility to use drop commands, because of the lack of the mysql-server. Neither phpmyadmin works because of that, nor can i connect via cmd (with admin-rights) and mysqld.exe.

A fresh installation has the same problem that the mysql-server won't start. So it can't be anything with the backups, because i didn't put the backups there. Like i said, it has to be something with the system, not only with the single installation (which of course can be add on top of the system-problem).